# Spring Data PageImpl not returning page with the correct size?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create a new `Page` using a list of objects retrieved from the database. First I get all the elements from the DB, convert it to a Stream and then use lambda to filter the results. Then I need a Page with a set number of elements, however, instantiating a new `PageImpl` doesn't seem to return a page with the correct size.

Here is my code:

```
List<Produtos> listaFinal;
Stream<Produtos> stream = produtosRepository.findAll().stream();
listaFinal = stream.filter(p -> p.getProdNome().contains("uio")).collect(Collectors.toList());

long total = listaFinal.size();
Page<Produtos> imp = new PageImpl<>(listaFinal,pageable,total);
```

Here's a screenshot from debugging:

[image]

Note the size in the Pageable object is set to 20 and it understands that it needs 4 pages to render the 70 elements, but it returns the whole list.

What am I missing?

**Edit answering the comment made by Thomas:**

I understand how to use Page to return just a slice of the data. The code I showed was my attempt to use a lambda expression to filter my collection. The problem for me is I want to use Java 8's lambda to query the database via Spring Data JPA. Im used to VB.NET's and Entity `function(x)` query expressions and was wondering how to do the same with Spring JPA.

In my repository, Im using `extends JpaRepository<Produtos, Integer>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Produtos>` which gives me access to `findAll(Predicate,Pageable)`. However, the Predicate is not typed so I cant simply use `p -> p.getProdNome().contains("uio")` in the query. I'm using SQL Server and Hibernate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After learning more about how Spring Data works I ended up using `@Query` annotations on my methods inside the JpaRepository implementations to properly query the DB and filter the results, eliminating the need to use a stream and then convert back to Page.

Here's how the code above would look in case anyone needs an example:

```
@Query("select p from Produtos p where p.prodNome = ?1")
public Page<Produtos> productsListByName(String prodNome, Pageable pageable)
```

Im aware of Spring's `findBy` methods but sometimes the method names become really difficult to read depending on the amount of parameters so I just stuck to JPQL.

Doing it this way the Page's content will always have up to the maximum amount of elements defined by you in the Spring configuration.

I also use a custom implementation of `PageImpl`, I'm not at work right now and don't have access to the code, but I'll post it whenever I can.

Edit: Custom implementation can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/sxw1qGen)

Comment: Nice! I will give this a shot with what I'm working on.

Comment: Can you provide me the code you have been using for PageImpl. I am facing same problem now!

Comment: Code added. Note that this implementation was needed in my case because I was dealing with a REST service, and the default implementation wasn't working for me, might be different in your case.

Comment: Moved custom implementation to another website since the other one was down.

Comment: @dubonzi what if the query is typedQuery ... how it will work , in my code it is not working ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62485592/pageable-in-spring-for-paging-on-listobject-is-not-working

Comment: Interesting, have you implemented another subclass of Page? Because as far as I have seen the TotalPage Property of PageImpl always returns the number of elements passed in the collection seem not right for me and would be simple to solve as I think

Answer (score 19):

To extend [stites' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32918031/1788806), a [PagedListHolder](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/support/PagedListHolder.html) is the way to go and here is how:

```
List<String> list = // ...

// Creation
PagedListHolder page = new PagedListHolder(list);
page.setPageSize(10); // number of items per page
page.setPage(0);      // set to first page

// Retrieval
page.getPageCount(); // number of pages 
page.getPageList();  // a List which represents the current page
```

If you need sorting, use another [PagedListHolder constructor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/support/PagedListHolder.html#PagedListHolder-java.util.List-org.springframework.beans.support.SortDefinition-) with a [MutableSortDefinition](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/support/MutableSortDefinition.html).

Answer (score 8):

`PageImpl` is not intended to perform any kind of pagination of your list. [From the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageImpl.html) you can see that it's just the "basic `Page` implementation" which almost sounds like what you want, but it's really misleading.

Use [`PagedListHolder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/support/PagedListHolder.html) which is a simple state holder for handling lists of objects, separating them into pages.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your code right, then your intent is to load all records from the database and and split them into x buckets that are collected in the `PageImpl`, right?

Thats not how it used to work. The actual intent of the `Pageable` and `Page` abstraction is NOT
having to query all the data but just the "slice" of data that is needed.

In your case you could query the data via `Page<X> page = repository.findAll(pageable);` and simply return that.
Page holds the records for the current page alongside some additional information like e.g., the total number of records and whether there is a next page.

In your client code you can use that information to render a list of records and generating next / prev links appropriately.
Note that a query with `Page<X>` as result type issues 2 queries (1 to determine the overall total count for the query and 1 for the actual page data).

If you don't need the information about the total number of results but still want to be able to generate a next link you should
use `Slice<X>` as a return type - since it only issues 1 query.

Comment: I edited my original question with my comment since it was too long to write here, take a look please! Thanks.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I have to use a DTO to map the output of the query to remove some hidden columns. So I first get all the results and then map the result to new output as per DTO. then I use PageImpl on the new result . But its showing all the records instead of paged info.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue and found the way for it.

The `SimpleJpaRepository` has the method:

```
public Page<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable) {
    TypedQuery<T> query = getQuery(spec, pageable);
    return pageable == null ? new PageImpl<T>(query.getResultList())
                : readPage(query, getDomainClass(), pageable, spec);
}
```

Which is used to return `Page<T>` in case you are extending `JpaRepository`. So we can use the same functionality here (need to rewrite the code, as Spring doesn't give you public method to have full pagination support).

If you look at the method `PageImpl<>(List<T> content, Pageable pageable, long total);` it just set's the value whatever you give in `pageable`. Here you are sending `content` as full list, but spring doesn't do it for it's internal purpose.

Need to replace `Page<Produtos> imp = new PageImpl<>(listaFinal,pageable,total);`

Following code:.

```
TypedQuery<User> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery); 
// Users type can be replaced with any other entity

query.setFirstResult(pageable.getOffset());
query.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());

List<User> users = query.getResultList();
Page<User> result = PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(users,pageable, 
                    () -> getCountForQuery(User.class));
```

Method `getCountForQuery`:

```
private Long getCountForQuery(Class<?> t) {

    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder=entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = criteriaBuilder
            .createQuery(Long.class);
    countQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(
            countQuery.from(t)));
    Long count = entityManager.createQuery(countQuery)
            .getSingleResult();

    return count;
}
```

You can find the usage of `PageableExecutionUtils.getPage` in:

```
readPage(TypedQuery<S> query, final Class<S> domainClass, 
         Pageable pageable, final Specification<S> spec)
```

Method in `SimpleJpaRepository` which is mostly used by `findAll` internal method.

Comment: Assume that in the data query you have more roots or joins, so predicates could involve more entities. How should be the count query?...You can't do a count query only from a single root...how should be the count query?...I have to redefine all roots and joins also for the count query?...Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

After applying a lot of methodes, this was the working solution in my case:

```
int pageSize = pageable.getPageSize();
long pageOffset = pageable.getOffset();
long total = pageOffset + list.size() + (list.size() == pageSize ? pageSize : 0);
Page<listType> page = new PageImpl<listType>(list, pageable,total)
```

Answer (score 0):

previously my code was written like this

```
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo,size);
    Query query = new Query().with(pageable);
```

and i was getting this for

"pageNumber": 0,
"pageSize": 5,
"size": 5,
"numberOfElements": 5,

"pageNumber": 0,
"pageSize": 10,
"size": 10,
"numberOfElements": 8,

8 is the total actual element i have in my DB

I changed that to this

```
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo,size);
    Query query = new Query();
```

now i'm getting the actual number of item for any size of page

"pageNumber": 0,
"pageSize": 5,
"size": 5,
"numberOfElements": 8,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).