# Why not receiving pageable details in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working in a spring boot project. I am required to return a list with pagination. Currently I can choose the page and size in parameters but i am not receiving page details like:

```
"last": false,
"totalElements": 20,
"totalPages": 7,
"size": 3,
"number": 0,
"sort": null,
"first": true,
"numberOfElements": 3
```

I am just receiving a normal response without that. I think I need to change method response type to ResponseEntity or Resources.
Any ideas?

Controller:

```
public List<PostOutputDTO> getTopicPosts(@PathVariable("id") UUID topicId, Pageable pageable) {
   return postService.getActivePosts(topicId, pageable);
```

Service:

```
 public List<PostOutputDTO> getActivePosts(UUID topicId, Pageable pageable) throws AccessDeniedException {
    Topic topic = topicRepo.findByIdAndDeactivatedAtIsNull(topicId).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("This topic doesn't exist."));
    if (topic.getType() != TopicType.GLOBAL) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException("This is not a global topic.");
    }
    return postAssembler.toResources(postRepo.findPostsByTopicAndDeactivatedAtIsNull(topic, pageable));
}
```

Assembler:

```
@Service
public class PostAssembler extends ResourceAssemblerSupport<Post, PostOutputDTO> {

    @Autowired
    private ForumUserAssembler forumUserAssembler;

    @Autowired
    private TopicAssembler topicAssembler;

    @Autowired
    private ContentRepo contentRepo;

    public PostAssembler() {
        super(PostController.class, PostOutputDTO.class);
    }

    public PostOutputDTO toResource(Post post) {
        return PostOutputDTO.builder()
                .uuid(post.getId())
                .topic(topicAssembler.toResource(post.getTopic()))
                .text(contentRepo.findByPostAndDeactivatedAtIsNull(post).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("This post doesn’t have content")).getText())
                .createdAt(post.getCreatedAt())
                .createdBy(forumUserAssembler.toResource(post.getCreatedBy()))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface TopicRepo extends JpaRepository<Topic, UUID> {

    Page<Topic> findAllByTypeAndDeactivatedAtIsNull(TopicType topicType, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust the return type to [`Page<PostOutputDTO>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html) instead of `List<PostOutputDTO>`.

The easiest way to convert a `List<PostOutputDTO>` to a `Page<PostOutputDTO>` is

```
public Page<PostOutputDTO> getTopicPosts(@PathVariable("id") UUID topicId, Pageable pageable) {
    return new PageImpl<>(postService.getActivePosts(topicId, pageable));
}
```

**Update:**

I still don't see the whole picture, but I hope the repository methods return `Page` instances,

```
Page<Post> findPostsByTopicAndDeactivatedAtIsNull(...);
Page<Topic> findAllByTypeAndDeactivatedAtIsNull(...);
```

so the problem comes from `PostAssembler#toResources` which returns a `List`, which we inaccurately transform into a `Page` back.

If I get you correctly, you are utilising `ResourceAssemblerSupport` to map an `Iterable<Post>` (more precisely, a `Page<Post>`) to a `List<PostOutputDTO>`.

What I am suggesting is to not use [`PostAssembler#toResources`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/mvc/ResourceAssemblerSupport.html#toResources-java.lang.Iterable-) and stick to [`PostAssembler#toResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/ResourceAssembler.html#toResource-T-) and [`Page#map`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html#map-java.util.function.Function-):

```
postRepo.findPostsByTopicAndDeactivatedAtIsNull(topic, pageable)
        .map(postAssembler::toResource);
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you!

Comment: @Chefk5 happy to help

Comment: Do you have an idea why "totalElements" does not show all the elements. It shows only in current page

Comment: @Chefk5 look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720768/spring-data-pageimpl-not-returning-page-with-the-correct-size

Comment: @Chefk5 you may not use `PageImpl` but return a `Page` directly from the repository

Comment: @Chefk5 it's hard to say because I don't know what your repository returns and what `postAssembler.toResources` does

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181230/discussion-between-chefk5-and-andrew-tobilko).

Comment: I didnt use the assembler at all and it worked..I tried that in a mock project. Will see tmrw if it works like that...because the issue is in the assembler as you pointed. Thanks alot for your time

Answer (score 1):

You must return Interface Page from spring:

A page is a sublist of a list of objects. It allows gain information about the position of it in the containing.

See the example:

```
public Page<PostOutputDTO>  getActivePosts(UUID topicId, Pageable pageable) {

    Page<PostOutputDTO>  list=postService.getActivePosts(topicId, pageable);

      return  list;

}
```

for more info see the [reference](https://ankushs92.github.io/tutorial/2016/05/03/pagination-with-spring-boot.html)

Comment: its an interface Page<Object> if postService return a  Page<PostOutputDTO> you can return it , its the same of return postService.getActivePosts(topicId, pageable);

Comment: you don't need to return an implementation new PageImpl<> because your repository must return a Pageable like this : public interface ExampleRepository extends  PagingAndSortingRepository<Example,Long> {
 public Page<Example> findAllExampleObjects( Pageable pageable);}

Comment: ok..now i have a problem in last line of service with the assembler...eventhough i changed return type to page